# Group data by 15 days interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need select all users who have placed more than 3 posts in the same category (sql) in the last year with a time interval of less than 15 days. 
The problem is in the last part "with a time interval of less than 15 days".

This is how I select users for 2018 and tags (you can run it on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new):

```
SELECT OwnerUserId, Id, CreationDate
FROM Posts
WHERE OwnerUserId IN (
    SELECT OwnerUserId
    FROM Posts 
    WHERE YEAR(Posts.CreationDate) >= 2018 AND YEAR(Posts.CreationDate) < 2019 
    AND Posts.Tags LIKE '%sql%'
    GROUP BY OwnerUserId,PostTypeId
    HAVING COUNT(PostTypeId) > 3
)
```

I think that I should firsty group by date range and then count. But I dont know how can do it. I read how to group by weeks, but it is not what I need because posts can be from different weeks.

In the end I should just get a list of users.

Comment: Great idea of using SEDE data as sample!

Comment: How do you define "category"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff for an example i choose "sql". in this data its a tag because almost every posts have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAG` function with offset parameter to find the date of the 2nd previous post, then calculate the date difference:

```
WITH questions AS (
    SELECT OwnerUserId
         , CreationDate AS PostDate
         , LAG(CreationDate, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerUserId ORDER BY CreationDate) AS PrevDate
    FROM Posts
    WHERE OwnerUserId IS NOT NULL    -- not community owned
    AND PostTypeId = 1               -- questions only
    AND CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' -- between 2018
    AND CreationDate < '2019-01-01'
    AND Tags LIKE '%<sql>%'          -- tagged sql
)
SELECT *
FROM questions
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, PrevDate, PostDate) <= 14
```

Comment: Thanks so much, its exactly what i need!

Answer (score 1):

You can get posts that meet these conditions by using window functions.  `lead()` can pick up the second record after this one, and then you can check whether this appears during the correct time period.

If I understand your terminology correctly:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             lead(CreationDate, 2) over (partition by OwnerUserId, PostTypeId order by CreationDate) as CreationDate_2
      from posts p
      where p.CreationDate >= '2018-01-01' and
            p.CreationDate < '2019-01-01' and
            p.Tags like '%sql%'
     ) 
where CreationDate_2 < dateadd(day, 15, CreationDate)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a beginner in sql, so cant fixed it quickly. i understant your idea, but  itreturned "The function 'lead' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY."